# js window.open and print not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am written a code something like this.. It is working fine in Mozilla Firefox where as in google chrome without writing any content in the document it is printing.. Please help me how to resolve this problem.

Suppose if I removed that printing statement then it is working fine but I need to print that window

```
function prepareInvoice(userDetails, courseId)
        {
            var a = "";
            a = a+"<html><head><title>Invoice | Palle University</title>";
            a = a + "<link href=\"../assets/css/bootstrap.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";
            //form=form+
            a = a + "</head><body><header id=\"header\" class=\"navbar-fixed-top\"> <div class=\"container\" > <div class=\"row\"  ><div class=\"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 logo-wrapper\">";
                a=a+"<a href=\"#\" style=\"text-decoration:none\"> <div class=\"pulogo\"><label style=\"color:white\">Palle<sup>®</sup></label>University</div></a>";
                a = a + "</div><div style=\"font-weight:bold;\" class=\"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-right\">Invoice</div></div></div></header>";
                a = a + "<section id=\"about\" class=\"clearfix\">";
                a = a + "<div class=\"container\" > <div class=\"row\"  ><div class=\"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6\">";
                a = a + "manish complex;<br>Mangammana palya main road;<br>Bommanahalli-560068;<br>Bangalore;Karnataka-India";
                a = a + "</div><div class=\"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6\">";
                a = a + "<b>Customer Details:</b><br>";
                if (userDetails.Lastname != "")
                    a = a + "Last Name:" + userDetails.Lastname + "<br>";
                if (userDetails.FirstName != "")
                    a = a + "First Name:" + userDetails.FirstName + "<br>";
                if (userDetails.Address != "")
                    a += "address:" + userDetails.Address + "<br>";
                if (userDetails.CityName != "")
                    a += "city:" + userDetails.CityName + "<br>";
                if (userDetails.State != "")
                    a += "state:" + userDetails.State + "<br>";
                if (userDetails.CountryName != "")
                    a += "Country:" + userDetails.CountryName + "<br>";
                if (userDetails.Email != "")
                    a += "email:" + userDetails.Email + "<br>";
                a = a + "</div></div></div>";
                a = a + "<div class=\"container\" > <div class=\"row\"> <div class=\"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12\">";
                a = a + "<table style=\"font-size:15px\" class=\"table table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin text-center\"><thead><tr class=\"text-center\"><td>Course Name</td><td>Purchased On</td><td>Expires On</td><td>Amount</td></tr></thead><tbody>";
                var cur_symbol='';
                var amount=0;
                for (i = 0; i < userDetails.LstCourses.length;i++)
                {

                    if (courseId == userDetails.LstCourses[i].CourseId) {
                        var monthNames = ["jan", "feb", "march", "april", "may", "june",
                                          "July", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
                        a = a + "<tr><td>" + userDetails.LstCourses[i].Course_displayname + "</td>";
                        var d = new Date(parseInt(userDetails.LstCourses[i].Paid_date.substr(6)));
                        var curr_date = d.getDate();
                        var curr_month = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
                        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                        var cur_symbol = '';
                        if (userDetails.LstCourses[i].Currency_code.toLowerCase() == "usd")
                            cur_symbol = "usd ";//"<i class=\"fa fa-usd\"></i>";
                        else if (userDetails.LstCourses[i].Currency_code.toLowerCase() == "inr")
                            cur_symbol = "inr ";//"<i class=\"fa fa-inr\"></i>";

                        a = a + "<td>" + curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year + "</td>";
                        d = new Date(parseInt(userDetails.LstCourses[i].Expire_date.substr(6)));
                        curr_date = d.getDate();
                        curr_month = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
                        curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                        a = a + "<td>" + curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year + "</td>";
                        amount = userDetails.LstCourses[i].Amount_paid;
                        a = a + "<td>" + cur_symbol + userDetails.LstCourses[i].Amount_paid + "</td></tr>";//display dollar or inr symbol.
                        //display the total amount based on the course id and a thank you ! message . 
                    }
                }
                a = a + "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Total: " + cur_symbol +" "+ amount + "</td></tr>";
                a = a + "</tbody></table></div></div></div>";
                a = a + "<div class=\"container\" > <div class=\"row\"> <div class=\"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center\">";
                a = a + "Thank you !</div></div></div>";
                //a = a + "<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Total:" + cur_symbol + amount + "</td></tr></table></div></div></div>";
                a = a + "</body></html>";
                //a.print();oUser.Lastname; oUser.Lastname;oUser.Address;
            //oUser.Email; oUser.CityName; oUser.State; oUser.CountryName;
                debugger;
                var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
                mywindow.document.write(a);
                mywindow.document.close();
                mywindow.focus();
                mywindow.print();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a div content

```
function printDivision() {
var printContents = document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = "<div align='center' style='padding: 5%;' >"
        + printContents + "</div>";
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```